# CSS Animation Stutters/Shakes in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Not sure why at all, but in Chrome the text inside of a moving div (thats moving using CSS transitions) stutters and shakes a bunch while in motion. It doesn't do this in Firefox, it's very very smooth over there and has the desired effect.

```css
#hidexpert {
display: block;
z-index: 99999;
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
top: 30%;
transition: right 1s ease;
}
#hidexpert:hover {
right: 220px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the full CSS/HTML. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/5XhkQ/embedded/result/

Comment: I can't reproduce that in my Chrome. The element moves smooth and the "Live Sales Chat" does the same. No stutters or shakes. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 38.0.2101.0 dev-m

Just downloaded Chromium too as a test and it works smooth over there. But it's never worked smoothly in my standard Chrome - it just now finally annoyed me enough to want to fix it. Maybe something in my about:flags is funky. Thanks for the heads up that its smooth in yours.

Answer (score -1):

Just use http://bassta.bg/demos/smooth-page-scroll/

you don't have to alter existing code at all. This overrides the default scroll behaviour.